# Need to center navigation menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

looking to get help on my navigation menu. please check it out at lofthairstudio.ie
its working ok but would like to have it centered in the middle of the page. have tried a few things but it will not move. float: right is the only one that moves the bar but obviously i want it centered.

```
.dropdown-menu {text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.dropdown-menu li { position: relative text-align: center;}
.dropdown-menu ul { position: absolute; nowhitespace: afterproperty; nowhitespace: afterproperty; nowhitespace: afterproperty; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 99; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transition: all .2s ease-in-out; margin: 10px 0 0 0; _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/ 
 text-align: center;
}
.dropdown-menu > li { float: left; display: block;text-align: center; }
.dropdown-menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; margin: 0; }
.dropdown-menu a { display: block; position: relative; font-family: 'MyWebFont';}
.dropdown-menu ul ul { top: 0; left: 100%; }
.dropdown-menu > li ul { min-width: 150px }
.dropdown-menu ul ul li { width: 100% }
/* position arrows */
.nav-menu .icon-angle-down { position: absolute; right: 13px; top: 50%; font-size: 12px; margin-top: -6px; }
.nav-menu .icon-angle-right { position: absolute; right: 20px; top: 50%; font-size: 12px; margin-top: -6px; }
/*styling*/
.nav-toggle { display: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; 

-moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; }
#navbar {background: #E4DDC8; border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF; border-top: 2px solid #FFF;  position: relative; 

margin-bottom: 10px;  }

.nav-menu {  float: left; border-right: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);  

}
.nav-menu a { font-size: 20px; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; color:#000; padding: 0 8px; text-decoration: none; 

font-weight: 700; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.2s 

ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;}
.nav-menu li { float: left; position: relative; }
.nav-menu li.dropdown a { padding-right: 30px }
.nav-menu > li > a {border-right: 1px solid #000; border-left: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,1); margin-top: 5px; 

margin-bottom:5px;}
.nav-menu > li:first-child { border-left: none }
.nav-menu li:first-child > a, .dropdown-menu li:first-child > a:hover { border-left: none }
.nav-menu > li > a:hover, .nav-menu > .current-menu-item > a, .navigation .current-menu-parent > a, .navigation 

.current-menu-parent > a:hover, .nav-menu > .current-menu-item > a:hover { color: #000; background: #E4DDC8;}

/*drop-down styles*/
.nav-menu ul { margin: 0; background: #E4DDC8; width: 190px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.nav-menu ul li { float: none; display: block; border-left: none; border-right: none; margin: 0; }
.nav-menu ul li:first-child { border-top: 0 }
.nav-menu ul li:last-child { border-bottom: 0 }
.nav-menu a { display: block; position: relative; text-align: center; }
.nav-menu .sub-menu li.current_page_item > a { color: #fff; background-color: #E4DDC8; }
.nav-menu ul a { display: block; padding: 10px; }
.nav-menu ul li { border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.1); border-top: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,1); }
.nav-menu ul a { color: #000; padding: 17px 15px; height: auto; text-align:left; margin: 0px; border: 0px; line-height:
```

Comment: post your html, please

Answer (score 1):

`.nav-menu li{ float:none; display:inline-block; }`

Comment: This is correct, but you should to remove 'float:left' from '.dropdown-menu li' and 'nav-menu' too.

Comment: Solution above worked!!!

thanks a million Frozenstorm your very kind!

regards
Gus